# ¿Porque no me trae los datos de la consulta sql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenas tardes estoy realizando una consulta en mysql dada una fecha me traiga el año y el mes y la referencia por ese mes, La consulta está buena pero no me esta trayendo nada, alguien que me ayude a encontrar el error.

```
<?php
//comprobamos que las fechas existan
if(isset($_POST["fecha_desde"])){
   $fecha_desde = $_POST["fecha_desde"];
}
if (isset ($_POST["fecha_hasta"])){
   $fecha_hasta = $_POST["fecha_hasta"]; 
   $fecha_desde = strtotime($fecha_desde);
   $fecha_hasta = strtotime($fecha_hasta);
   $fecha_desde = date('Y-m',$fecha_desde);
   $fecha_hasta = date('Y-m',$fecha_hasta);

   $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT referencia, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y%m'), SUM(cantidad), COUNT(referencia) FROM pedidos_detalle INNER JOIN pedidos ON pedidos_detalle.id_pedido = pedidos.id WHERE $_POST[fecha_desde] = DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y%m') BETWEEN '$fecha_desde' AND '$fecha_hasta' GROUP BY referencia, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y%m'), ORDER BY referencia, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y%m') ASC");
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
       echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0], $row[1]</option>"; 
?>
```

Comment: me parece que te hace falta cerrar el while "}"

Comment: el while esta cerrado mas abajito

Comment: podes darle un `print_r($rs); ` para ver la consulta que esta generando y ver si todo esta correcto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ademas de cerrar las el if yel while, comprueba la consulta, porque el where esta mal estructurado.

```
 WHERE $_POST[fecha_desde] = DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y%m') BETWEEN '$fecha_desde' AND '$fecha_hasta'
```

Te has dejado un AND y una variable, o esa condicion no es posible

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
p.referencia, 
DATE_FORMAT(pd.fecha_pedido, '%Y%m') as 'fecha', 
SUM(pd.cantidad), 
COUNT(p.referencia) 
FROM pedidos_detalle pd INNER JOIN pedidos p
ON pd.id_pedido = p.id
WHERE pd.fecha_pedido >= $fecha_desde 
AND pd.fecha_pedido  <= $fecha_hasta
GROUP BY p.referencia, fecha
ORDER BY fecha asc;
```

Podrias publicar la estructura de tus tablas para verlo mejor. Y prueba en la bd directamente si te devuelve algo tu query con las fechas que tu designes. Dentro de tu query haces $_POST[fecha_Desde] pero ya la habias introducido en $fecha_desde.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 brackets sin cerrar en tu código, Uno de un IF y el otro del WHILE. Empieza por cerrarlos, o si ya los tienes bien postea el código correcto.